# How to get the right datetime format if this is the current format 'Sat 18 May, 4:18 am'?

Tags: php

I want to convert 'Sat 18 May, 4:18 am' to MySQL datetime format('Y-m-d H:i:s').

```
$post_datetime = 'Sat 18 May, 4:18 am';
$format        = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$dt            = new DateTime($post_datetime);

echo $dt->format($format);
```

The problem is the formatted datetime is in future `2016-05-21 04:18:00`. I'm assuming this is because there is no year specified. Any solution?

Comment: There are an infinite number of Thursday, 1st January. You must have a year for it to make any sense.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to determine the appropriate datetime in that current format?

Comment: Correct. It is not possible without a year.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by converting a time string into a timestamp and then generating a date/time string again from that time stamp

```
date('d-M-Y', strtotime('Thu 1 Jan, 4:09 pm'));
```

Comment: no. it's not working. i tried this one date('d-M-Y', strtotime('Sat 18 May, 4:18 am')); the result is 21-May-2016 which is supposed to be 18-May-2013.

Comment: You didn't defined the year how can it be possible. @KelvinMartinLigue

Comment: Yeah. I thought date function is smart enough to determine the appropriate date/time in that format.

Comment: OMG....! How can it be that possible. First answer my question `Sat 18 May, 4:18 am` I wanted the output within `Y-m-d H:i:s` what'll be the output of this date

Comment: Oops i forget, this date don't have a year specified.

What i want to say is you can convert a text datetime into unix timestamp using strtotime() function

here is the source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

appologies

You need to specify year also :P